# PHP CMS components

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I am exploring how CMS's in PHP work.  I am talking about full-powered, fully developed CMS's like Drupal, Wordpress, and Joomla.  What are the main components and systems that are incorporated into something like this.

For example; I know you will need a page loader to handle all page requests (direct all requests to index.php using the .htaccess file), you will need a database class, a templating class, and a hook system to provide user extendability.  What else am I missing?

(Also, is there a book that explains the working components of a full-fledged CMS?)

Comment: Maybe creating a CMS from scratch while following a tutorial will help you understand all of the different components. [PHP MVC Tutorial](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/)

Comment: Just out of curiousity and because I don't know how to send messages, what is your experience level?  Why are you trying to make a CMS?  There are some pretty good solutions out there.

Comment: I am relatively experienced with PHP.  I understand OOP, inheritance, abstraction, and all that stuff.  I am not trying to create a new CMS, rather adapt a plugin system for a photography website that can allow the client I am building it for to write plugins and use it.

Comment: However, if I do become very advanced in my PHP skills I may create a small CMS just for the experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd second starting with something like Wordpress (not a real CMS I know) to get a feel for the sort of things you want your one to do. From there you could move up to Drupal or if you still feel the need to, look into building one in a framework (Codeigniter is a good one to start with).

Personally after a few years of rebuilding a CMS for each client I wish I'd got into Drupal quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Google MVC in PHP. There are plenty of frameworks off which to build such a tool. Although, I beg to differ on Wordpress. Wordpress is a blogging system, not what I would call a "fully-fleged" CMS.

I found [this book](http://davidwalsh.name/php5-cms-framework-development).

And I would strongly recommend this book on [building a CMS with the Zend Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218797).

Another solid CMS to consider is [Concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/).

Comment: I hate wordpress, but I still have a wordpress blog.  I agree though, not a CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick shoutout for ez Publish. It is a rock solid PHP based CMS, some of the best code i've seen.